# How to make my app accessible with subdomains?

Tags: angular, spring-boot, networking, ibm-cloud, subdomain

I am trying to build a multi-tenancy app using Spring boot as back end and Angular as front end. I am considering deploying it on IBM Cloud.

The idea is to give each client a subdomain to access the application. For example if the domain name i am using to access the app is app.com, Then Client1 could also access the app using client1.app.com.

Then in Angular i use this code to extract that subdomain to query the database:

```
getSubdomain() {
const domain = window.location.hostname;
if (domain.indexOf('.') < 0 || 
  domain.split('.')[0] === 'example' || domain.split('.')[0] === 'lvh' || domain.split('.')[0] === 'www') {
  this.subdomain = '';
} else {
  this.subdomain = domain.split('.')[0];
}
console.log('subdomain is:'+ this.subdomain);
}
```

but i still don't know how to make my app respond to subdomians both in development and production environments.

Currently in my dev environment i can only access the app using localhost:3000. I tried editing the hosts file (on Windows) by adding gado.com , abc.gado.com but although i can ping those names i can't access the app using any.

In production i have no idea how to implement this. I mean is this an app or HTTP server?

---

**Update**

Sorry if I wasn't clear enough. I'll break the requirement down to steps with my thoughts about how i think it should be done. Please correct me or fill any gaps at any point.

Let's say i have an app deployed on a server with a public ip 9.9.9.9.

1- Now to make people access this app using the domain name gado.com for example, What should i do? Based on my limited knowledge i should go to an ISP or hosting vendor and purchase a domain name and then the ISP maps it to the ip address of my server using a DNS server.

2- Also i want users to reach the same app/ip with any subdomain (The subdomain must be present in the browsers URL field all the time). Based on my research i found this concept of a wildcard subdomain where you insert * instead of a subdomain name. But when i asked a hosting vendor about this they said they don't provide this feature. So should i try another vendor or is this something that i should implement.

I did something like this before, the app was deployed on the cloud but to access it users had to use a url that has the VM ip address [https://*ip-address*/GxSystems/faces/SignIn](https://_ip-address_/GxSystems/faces/SignIn). To make it easier i used the companies cpanel and added a new subdomain and mapped it to the url above. Only problem is that it was just redirection. The url changed from sub.domain.com to the apps original url which is not what i want. i want the url to stay "sub.domain.com"

3- Is there any configuration or setup has to be done on the machine that hosts the application. I mean like a configuration for the web server on that machine to accommodate the previous steps.

So I think my question basically is what are the steps of mapping my application server to a domain name and wild card subdomains instead of using it's ip address directly?

Answer (score 0):

you can build your application with --base-href and --deploy-url. check https://angular.io/cli/build

Comment: --base-href is for pointing to the index.html page and --deploy-url is for the deployment location of the files. Those has nothing to do with sub-domaining the app!